# Property "CWebApplication.curl" is not defined

Tags: curl, yii, yii-extensions

Hi guys i am new to both here and Yii i am creating an web app using api for that i am using curl

i have done steps as per tutorial given in yii.

but it still shows this error

> Property "CWebApplication.curl" is not defined

help me with your ideas..

Comment: did you enable curl in your server?

Comment: [`CWebApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication) doesn't have a `curl` property. Could you add the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: @topher how to add that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely you have not configured Yii's Curl extension. Open the main.php in the protected/config.

find your "components" value and add the curl value like below

```
'components'=>array(
    'curl' => array(
         'class' => 'ext.curl.Curl',
         //'options' => array(/.. additional curl options ../)
    ),
)
```

this assumes that you are using the extension from http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl/

if this is not your extension the solution is most likely the same just modify the "ext.curl.Curl" to point to the folder with your curl extension.

Comment: Yep Forgot to say i already got answer that day itself as u said it is the correct answer...Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: I assumed that to be the case since the question was 24 days old, but I figured for completeness I could leave an answer for future people